# yup validation library TypeError: yup__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, yup

I have installed yup and tried to validate my form with this, however when I try to import it to a file I get this error. I do not even run the handler, it just errors me out on page load. I use it with react.

this is my code

```
import * as yup from "yup";

export const detailsSchema = yup.object().shape({
    cheeseType: yup()
        .string()
        .isRequired()
});
```

I tried to rm -rf node_modules, I did not help.

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Can you change import to this: `import * as Yup from "yup";`  and try again ?

Answer (score 0):

It solved this error I used wrong method - isRequired() instead of required() and also here I was wrong:

```
cheeseType: yup()
        .string()
        .isRequired()
```

should be

```
cheeseType: yup
        .string()
        .isRequired()
```

so the correct schema looks like

```
cheeseType: yup
        .string()
        .required()
```

All the best! :)